# Node, Express, Swig Template - Variable in HTML attribute

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, swig-template

I'm using http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/ as my template engine for a Node/Express app.

I can pass data into my template fine, but I'm having trouble using variables.

I have:

```
{% for person in people %}
    <input type="radio" name="id" value="{{ person._id }}" id="id_123" /> <label for="id_123">{{ 'id = ' + person._id }}</label><br />
{% endfor %}
```

The `people` object is ok, and the loop works. However you'll notice that I'm trying to use `person._id` twice - the first one doesn't work, the second one does.

```
value="{{ person._id }}"
// value="[object Object]"

<label for="id_123">{{ 'id = ' + person._id }}</label>
// <label for="id_123">id = 568bc95f317e30e813541ab0</label>
```

Why do I get `[object Object]` when trying to use `person._id` within a HTML attribute, then get the correct value I'm after when using `person._id` inside HTML tags..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, the `person._id` is actually a Mongoose `ObjectId`, which now makes sense to me. However when I `console.log` it, it shows a string.

Anyway, just doing `'' + person._id` works for what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use tilde for this purpose:

```
{{ 'id = ' ~ person._id }}
```

Answer (score 0):

`person._id` is a mongoose object which have its own properties. So if you use `person._id` in `swig` template it takes it as an object. By doing `'id = ' + person._id`, it converts it internally to `person._id_toString()`.

Try using:

```
value={{ person._id.toString() }} if you want _id to be string
```